# Thread safe QQueue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex

In a Qt application, I need to add items from one thread, and consume them from another. As Qt docs state about container classes:

> ... they are thread-safe in situations where they are used as read-only
>   containers by all threads used to access them.

I assume I need to create a thread safe version, or protect it with a mutex. Is there any recommended solution? Like using directly the Qt event loop, or any thread-safe class I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

For a queue, yes you need a thread safe version. I recommend QMutex together with QMutexLocker as it handles the unlock automatically.

If your consumer and producer work on different parts of the buffer, I recommend a [semaphore](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qtcore-semaphores-example.html) instead.

> Semaphores make it possible to have a higher level of concurrency than
>   mutexes. If accesses to the buffer were guarded by a QMutex, the
>   consumer thread couldn't access the buffer at the same time as the
>   producer thread. Yet, there is no harm in having both threads working
>   on different parts of the buffer at the same time.